# Вывод букв\слов во время выполнения программы

Tags: java, алгоритм, intellij-idea

Захотелось написать простенький транслятор латинских букв в азбуку Морзе и обратно.Всё получается, все хорошо, вот только хочется фичу. Фичей выбрал следующее:

По мере написания в консоль слов необходимо, чтобы программа незамедлительно выдавала перевод(иначе говоря альтернатива классу `Scanner`, без нажатий на энтер, прямо во время работы программы).

Возможно ли такое, если да - куда копать?

Comment: Возможно, конечно. Можно без вопросов перерендеривать консоль, но мне самому интересно, можно ли впилиться в нужный поток, чем ломиться в лоб.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, возможно. Простейший способ - использовать [JLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/downloads.html) или [JLine2](https://github.com/jline/jline2).

Они достаточно просты в освоении и код хорошо документирован, сам недавно познакомился с данной библиотекой.

Comment: А руками без либ как-либо возможно?

Comment: @Asgard, да, можно, но вам придется реализовать примерно то, что реализовано внутри этой библиотеки :)